# Increment a counter once until value is greater than if statement (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
if (step < 1) {
    accSteps.push(parseInt(step));
}

for (i = 0; i < accSteps.length; i++) { 
    zOutput++;
    document.getElementById("zVal").innerHTML = zOutput;
}
```

The `step` variable is z co-ordinate from an mbed accelerometer to count number of steps. Currently, when the z-coordinate is < 1 (i.e. a step has been made), it will carry on adding steps to the counter until the z-coordinate is 1 or greater. How do I increment by just 1 for the whole duration until z-coordinate is 1 or greater again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a flag for that.

```
// Put this flag somewhere only executed once
var hasRegisteredStep = false;

if (step < 1 && hasRegisteredStep === false) {
    accSteps.push(parseInt(step));
    hasRegisteredStep = true;
} else if(step > 0) {
   hasRegisteredStep = false; // Reset the flag if greater than 0
}

for (i = 0; i < accSteps.length; i++) { 
    zOutput++;
    document.getElementById("zVal").innerHTML = zOutput;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Just add that condition in the for loop:

```
if (step < 1) {
        accSteps.push(parseInt(step));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < accSteps.length && step < 1; i++) { 
        zOutput++;
        document.getElementById("zVal").innerHTML = zOutput;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I haven't made the question clear enough, this still does exactly the same as my code above. Instead of it adding 1 to the counter constantly whilst step < 1 I want it to just add 1 once until step => 1.

Comment: @Djoni I'm afraid that's still a bit unclear. Could you clarify with an example?